# Unable to start Rails in VM within Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I have installed rails on Vagrant and trying to create my first rails application, however "rails server" is taking a long time (i.e, never seem to complete after). I am using Windows and have installed Vargant and virtual box. On my Vagrant file, I have also updated core cpu and memory to the following

```
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
```

but still can't seem to start rails on my VM
Rails version is 4.2.6

[below is the screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of73M.gif)

**Note:  The command prompt is never returned after this point**

Comment: It looks like it is working. The server will continue to run until you hit `ctrl+c` to stop it. Open a 2nd terminal if needed. Can you bring up http://localhost:3000 in a browser and see the welcome page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails server` like any web server is meant to run as a persistent process. It sits there and waits for web requests - so the behavior you are seeing is actually exactly how it is supposed to work.

To exit the server (and most unix programs) you can send the terminate command with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

You can also run the server in the background in Bash by starting it with:

```
rails s &
```

You can then return it to the foreground with `fg`. Although I usually just open another shell window instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your rails server is running properly.

But you need to whitelist that IP address.

In config/environments/development.rb include the following lines

```
config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '10.0.2.2'
```

Read here for more information...

https://github.com/rails/web-console#configweb_consolewhitelisted_ips